# Trying to give a (non-rotating) black hole an electric dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes

Suppose there is a Schwarzschild black hole. You add positrons to the north "pole" and electrons to the south "pole". From an external observer, objects that you add end up "stuck" to the horizon. Thus, the positrons and electrons get stuck at the poles and you end up with a nice dipole.

However, this is not allowed because of the pesky no hair theorem. So how does the field end up "unstuck", and approximately how quickly would the dipole dissipate from the point of view of an external observer for i.e. a 10 solar mass black hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be a static dipole field.  It would have some dynamics associated with it, and there would be net radiation.  The no-hair theorem only applies to late-time, evolved spacetimes.  And is about the horizon itself, not about apparent observations made by distant observers.

Less rambly, more bullet-pointy answer:

1. Distant observers would see a time-dependent electric field that would contain the information about the radiation falling in.  It would not be a static dipole field
2. The horizon itself, at the late times for which the no-hair theorem is relevant, will have absorbed all of the charge, and would have a geometry only depending on the net charge absorbed

Comment: And would there be an observeable dipole, say, a few years later.

Comment: @blademan9999: no, the late time black hole would have an electric field that depends only on the net charge absorbed, and would have no net electric dipole moment.  The field would even itself out through having a nonzero, time-dependent, dipole radiation term in the meantime.